# MySQL: Creating a view with table.*

Tags: mysql

Did search for this answer but didn't find so far (perhaps I did look for wrongs terms).

If create a view in MySQL:

```
CREATE VIEW view1 as
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

After I have (execute this) the definition of view1 is like this:

```
SELECT table1.field1, table1.field2 [..] FROM table1;
```

- Why does MySQL change my definition of the view from '*' to 'table1.field1, table1.field2 [..]'?
- If I add some new fields to table1 then they would be not in view1
- What can I do against it?

Thanks folks.

Comment: If you change the table, you invalidate the view anyway.  Listing the columns is much safer.

Comment: Thank you. If you are talking from views I use for access from PHP or so. But I just wanna make a internal view, then it is IMHO ok. Is there configuration, which MySQL save views as I enter e.g. 'SELECT * FROM table1' ?

Comment: '*' is just short hand for 'all the columns (in the tables)', so that's the way it's parsed by the query processor. If this is a problem, then it's highly likely that there is a flaw in your schema design.

Comment: Does those comments tell me that there is no configuration in MySQL to turn off the 'translation' from `*` to `table1.field1, table1.field2 [..]` ?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means. Once you add a column, you will have to alter all your * views on that table, too, unfortunately. I don't know of any option to prevent this.